# Google Cloud AutoML compute hours

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, automl, google-cloud-automl

How do I select compute hours if I would like to training the model faster? More compute hours or less? Do compute hours get distributed in parallel for data/model parallelism or it is just one compute node running that amount of time? What are the criteria for training to finish?

It is not obvious from this page:
https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/pricing

Also it appears that one compute hour runs very fast (~15 minutes).